# Account Manager and Auth Token

Tags: android, accountmanager

I am considering using the Android AccountManager of creating my custom AccountAuthenticator etc. But, the server i am trying to connect (code for connection is written and working) doesn't provide me with a Auth Token so i don't have to sent the user password everytime i want to sync. So i am asking is there a way to implement AccountAuthenticator without having the ability of using Auth Token just an encrypted password??? Any ideas is more than welcomed, also some assistance of code inserting points would be fantastic.

My regards,
Ribben

Answer (score 1):

`AccountAuthenticator` by default simply saves the password in a database. If you want to encrypt it, you should do so in your implementation. This leaves the question with what key and where will you store it though. If you simply embed it in the app, it will be trivial to extract. Here is a sample implementation that saves an Admob API password. It doesn't encrypt it though:

https://github.com/AndlyticsProject/andlytics/blob/master/src/com/github/andlyticsproject/admob/AdmobAccountAuthenticator.java

Comment: hey man, thanks for the reply, as i said in my post my server doesn't provide me with an auth token... So could you be more explainatory with the code you provided cause as far of my understanding i can see that your server is using an auth token!

Comment: The code shows how to save your password and lets you get it via the `AccountManager`. You don't have to use it as is, it's just a sample. Check the whole project on Github to see how it's used.

Comment: thanks so much for the code but as for now i don't know if i can use the accountmanager without having a auth token... So my first concern is that.